# Your org doesn't have access to component flexipage:column

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-page, summer20

Receive the following error when deploying a lightning record page. "Your org doesn't have access to component flexipage:column"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure Dynamic Forms is enabled in the target environment.
Setup > User Interface > Record Page Settings > Enable Dynamic Forms